# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' , but django is installed

Tags: python, django

I am installing Django. Following commands were executed successfully:

```
pipenv install djangorestframework
pipenv shell
django-admin startproject api_example
cd api_example
```

This command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Gives these error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: Did you activate Virtualenv and install django on it?

Comment: Make sure you run `pipenv shell` to activate the virtual environment before you run `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Have you tried `pipenv install django` too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install django and then djangoframework.

```
pipenv install django
```

Try this and then run your application.